# unmatched records should be pulled in the bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, match

Desired resultset:

in below query am getting the records grouped by legacy and source table and comparing the result if the value is matching then my flag column will populate match
but i want unmatched records as well in output ( in the attachment HTC product is not present in the source table hence this record is not populating ) i need HTC as well in my result - pls help

[image]
query framed:

```
with legacy as (select product,sum(premium) as premium_l,reportdate
from Tab_legacy
group by product,reportdate),

source as (select product,sum(premium) as premium_s,reportdate
from Tab_src
group by product,reportdate)

select legacy.product,legacy.premium_l,source.premium_s,
case when legacy.premium_l = source.premium_s then 'match' else 'unmatch' end as match_flg,
round((legacy.premium_l - source.premium_s )/source.premium_s,2) as Diff,
source.reportdate
from legacy join source
on legacy.reportdate = source.reportdate
and legacy.product = source.product
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full join`:

```
with legacy as (
      select product, sum(premium) as premium_l, reportdate
      from Tab_legacy
      group by product, reportdate
     ),
     source as (
      select product, sum(premium) as premium_s, reportdate
      from Tab_src
      group by product, reportdate
     )
select product, reportdate, legacy.premium_l, source.premium_s,
       (case when legacy.premium_l = source.premium_s
             then 'match' else 'unmatch'
        end) as match_flg,
       round((legacy.premium_l - source.premium_s )/source.premium_s,2) as Diff,
source.reportdate
from legacy full join
     source
     using (reportdate, product);
```

Note the changes:

- `full join` instead of `join`.
- `using` instead of `on`.  This makes it easier to include the key values in the `select` (otherwise you need `coalesce()` logic).
- `reportdate` in the `select`.  It is part of the `join` so you should include it.

Comment: previous record count 4 but now i see 5 records but i see only null values for all the columns for 5th records

Comment: Product reportdate Legacy premium Source premium Match Flg Diff
NULL NULL         Null                         NULL                   Unmatch NULL
for that unmatched record i am geeting only null value didnt get the product name as HTC  and the corresponding premium value  - pls advice

Comment: @Ram . . . There should not be `NULL` values for *all* the columns.  In particular, the first two should not be `NULL` -- unless there are `NULL`s in your data.